# Heroku Java WAR app that was working now failing: "Unable to access jarfile webapp-runner-7.0.40.0.jar"

Tags: java, heroku, war

Our Java WAR app - just a stateless Java web service - has been running fine for the last 3 years on Heroku but after some activity presumably initiated by Heroku on Friday:

> heroku-postgresql: Update HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED by heroku-postgresql

the app now logs this error on a dyno restart:

```
2017-08-14T19:37:10.491690+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `${PRE_JAVA}java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar webapp-runner-7.0.40.0.jar --port ${PORT} ${WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS} cv-services-1.0.0.war`
2017-08-14T19:37:12.584664+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-08-14T19:37:12.585526+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-08-14T19:37:12.575166+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-08-14T19:37:12.503570+00:00 app[web.1]: Unable to access jarfile webapp-runner-7.0.40.0.jar
```

and returns a 503 (service unavailable) error.

Heroku support say the problem:

> falls outside the nature of the Heroku Support policy

If you have experienced and resolved this sort of problem - especially recently - or have insight please answer.

**PS**

heroku info outputs:

```
Addons:         heroku-postgresql:dev
Auto Cert Mgmt: false
Dynos:          web: 1
Git URL:        https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxx.git
Owner:          xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com
Region:         eu
Repo Size:      0 B
Slug Size:      0 B
Stack:          cedar
Web URL:        https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/
```

Comment: When was the last time you deployed the app?

Comment: @codefinger 3 years ago.

Comment: Can you share the output of these commands: `heroku run java -version`, `heroku info`.

Comment: Also `heroku run ls` while you're at it

Comment: @codefinger Added the `heroku info` output to the question. The other two give "No app specified" or if I add the "--app xxxxxx" I get "Couldn't find that app".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but the Heroku `cedar` stack (a.k.a. Cedar-10) was [shutdown 2 years ago](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/701). You could follow the steps to update your app, but I think you're better off creating a new app, which you can do with the following commands:

```
$ heroku create
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy
$ heroku deploy:war cv-services-1.0.0.war
```

This assumes you have a copy of the `cv-services-1.0.0.war` file. The `deploy:war` command will deploy it on the latest (heroku-16) stack, with the latest Java (8), and latest Tomcat (8.5).

Comment: Just went looking for the WAR with this in mind. Will give it a go.

Comment: Works when created as a new app. Will see if replacing the existing app also works. Looking promising...

Comment: The "heroku deploy:war cv-services-1.0.0.war --app xxxxxx" didn't work first time to the original app. But in the "Settings" tab of the Heroku web UI an "Upgrade" button was showing next to the "Stack" for the app and clicking it displayed a message that said "heroku-16 will be used on next deploy". I then did the "heroku deploy:war cv-services-1.0.0.war --app xxxxxx" and the app now works at the original URL. Thanks for the clear and to the point directions here - problem solved.